# PHP or JavaScript periodic function call?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database

Is there any way to periodically check a database in PHP or JavaScript?

I want to perform a database query periodically in a single page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What GSto said. Quick example using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.get('http://url/script', null, function(data) {
    console.log('Server said: ' + data);
  }
}, 5000); // every 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nnevala's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136683/php-or-javascript-periodic-fuction-call/4136763#4136763), but it may cause problems if the request and your script takes longer than five seconds to execute.

It may be better to use a `setTimeout` recursive call:

```
function poll() {
    $.get('http://url/script', null, pollHandler);
}

function pollHandler(data) {
    console.log('Server said: ' + data);

    setTimeout(poll, 5000);
}
```

(The functions are split to prevent a memory leak.)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript with the `setInterval` function to call a function that makes an Ajax request to a PHP script, which will handle all of the database logic.

Comment: can u elaborate with an example? plz